# Closest (geometric) point as foreign key

Tags: database, postgresql

We have two (PostgreSQL 9.2) tables. First `cities`:

```
 loc_id    | integer               | not null
 name      | character varying(40) | 
 gps_coord | point                 |
```

followed by `weather_stations`:

```
 s_id        | integer                | not null
 location    | character varying(255) | not null
 height      | integer                | 
 city_loc_id | integer                | 
 gps_coord   | point                  |
```

**Using their point coordinates, how can we find the closest city of a weather station?** I want to use this city to fill the foreign keys of `weather_stations` (which are all NULL at the moment), namely `city_loc_id`. (Is having such a foreign key a good idea?)

I realize I must use the closest point operator (##) somehow but I am slightly lost when it comes to write the query.

Comment: I think ## is for if you have an array of points on the right operand, or a geometric structure on the right operand that spans more than one point, such as a line. I think what you really want to do is make a subquery that returns the row with the minimum euclidean distance from the point you are considering (e.g. do a min over calculating the euclidean distance between point 1 and point 2) and return that.

Comment: Regarding it being a good idea - cities change names, are abandoned/destroyed/etc, are created by fiat declaration of a government body, are split into two or more separate entities, combined, etc. So I wouldn't use a city as a foreign key, personally, since all this happens independently of the lifetime of a weather station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Thanks for the help.

```
UPDATE weather_stations
    SET city_loc_id = (
        SELECT c.loc_id
        FROM cities c
        ORDER BY weather_stations.gps_coord <-> c.gps_coord
        LIMIT 1 );
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a distance operator which is likely what you're looking for: `select point1 <-> point2`. (There also is earthdistance, but it seems overkill for your purpose.)